# How to compare a field of a file with current timestamp and print the greater and lesser data?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

How do I compare current timestamp and a field of a file and print the matched and unmatched data. I have 2 columns in a file (see below)

```
oac.bat 09:09
klm.txt 9:00
```

I want to compare the timestamp(2nd column) with current time say suppose(10:00) and print the output as follows.

**At 10:00**

*greater.txt*

```
xyz.txt 10:32
mnp.csv 23:54
```

*Lesser.txt*

```
oac.bat 09:09
klm.txt 9:00
```

Could anyone help me on this please ?

I used `awk $0 > "10:00"`, which gives me only 2nd column details but I want both the column details and I am taking timestamp from system directly from system with a variable like

```
d=`date +%H:%M`
```

Comment: [edit] your question so it's possible to get the posted expected output from the posted sample input. It should be a [mcve], emphasis on **Complete**.

Comment: @EdMorton, as for me, it is quite enough what he has already posted. There is a sample input, and two sample output files.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov without any input or output at all would be enough for some people too but the SO rules of [ask] tell people how to post a question that will get the most people interested in helping them and the highest probability of a good answer and those rules include posting a [mcve] which includes concise, testable sample input and expected output rather than disconnected fragments of both.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can just use it's builtin time functions:

```
awk 'BEGIN{now = strftime("%H:%M")} {
    split($NF,t,/:/)
    cur=sprintf("%02d:%02d",t[1],t[2])
    print > ((cur > now ? "greater" : "lesser") ".txt")
}' file
```

With other awks just set `now` using `-v` and `date` up front, e.g.:

```
awk -v now="$(date +"%H:%M")" '{
    split($NF,t,/:/)
    cur = sprintf("%02d:%02d",t[1],t[2])
    print > ((cur > now ? "greater" : "lesser") ".txt")
}' file
```

The above is untested since you didn't provide input/output we could test against.

Comment: These scripts will fail, if the first column contains a colon (`:`) and/or a space. And the 1st column looks like a filename, which could well contain a colon as well as a space, e.g. for `file abc.txt 7:00` the script will try to split `abc.txt` with `:`, which will cause an undefined behavior. The scripts will also fail, if the time column contains an invalid time, e.g. `invalid_time`.

Comment: _OP hasn't suggested anything like that as a possibility_ - _How do I compare current timestamp and a field of a **file**..._ - the OP. In my understanding "a file" refers to a filename (the other case is the file contents, but it is very unlikely, right?). Besides, `klm.txt`, and `mnp.csv` look like filenames to me. And a space is allowed to be a part of filename. I wouldn't use a software based on such assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Bash**

The script can be implemented in pure Bash with the help of `date` command:

```
# Current Unix timestamp
let cmp_seconds=$(date +%s)

# Read file line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
  let line_seconds=$(date -d "${line##* }" +%s) || continue

  (( line_seconds <= cmp_seconds )) && \
    outfile=lesser || outfile=greater

  # Append the line to the file chosen above
  printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "${outfile}.txt"
done < file
```

In this script, `${line##* }` removes the longest match of `'* '` (*any character followed by a space*) pattern from the front of `$line` thus fetching the last column (the time). The time column is supposed to be in one of the following formats: `HH:MM`, or `H:MM`. Actually, `date`'s `-d` option argument

> can be in almost any common format. It can contain month names, time zones, ‘am’ and ‘pm’, ‘yesterday’, etc.

We use the flexibility of this option to convert the time (`HH:MM`, or `H:MM`) to Unix timestamp.

The `let` builtin allows arithmetic to be performed on shell variables. If the last `let` expression fails, or evaluates to zero, `let` returns `1` (error code), otherwise `0` (success). Thus, if for some reason the time column is in invalid format, the iteration for such line will be skipped with the help of `continue`.

**Perl**

Here is a Perl version I have written just for fun. You may use it instead of the Bash version, if you like.

```
# For current date
#cmp_seconds=$(date +%s)
# For specific hours and minutes
cmp_seconds=$(date -d '10:05' +%s)

perl -e '
my @t = localtime('$cmp_seconds');
my $minutes = $t[2] * 60 + $t[1];
while (<>) {
  / (\d?\d):(\d\d)$/ or next;
  my $fh = ($1 * 60 + $2) > $minutes ? STDOUT : STDERR;
  printf $fh "%s", $_;
}' < file >greater.txt 2>lesser.txt
```

The script computes the number of minutes in the following way:

```
HH:MM = HH * 60 + MM minutes
```

If the number of minutes from the file are greater then the number of minutes for the current time, it prints the next line to the standard output, otherwise to standard error. Finally, the standard output is redirected to `greater.txt`, and the standard error is redirected to `lesser.txt`.

I have written this script for demonstration of another approach (algorithm), which can be implemented in different languages, including Bash.

Comment: That will be so immensely slow that by the time it finishes running on a moderately sized file the current date will have changed so you should save that before entering the loop! It also contains bugs caused by not implementing fundamental shell constructs properly that will corrupt the data on output (e.g. it will interpret backslashes in the file names) and is a well known anti-pattern. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks, I have fixed the backslashes. But are you sure about the time change? `date -d '10:05'` currently returns `1479351960` which corresponds to `Thu Nov 17 10:06:00 +07 2016` on my machine. The same command will return the same value until the next day (Nov 18). So yes, there is a bug, if the script will run somewhere around midnight. Also, have you made benchmarks, or just trusting the words in the answer? E.g. how many lines will be processed with this script in 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes I am positive about the time change and you don't need to test it to know that a shell loop invoking an external tool once for every line of input will be extremely slow but test it yourself if you like and you'll find it is literally orders or magnitude slower than the awk script I posted. btw since you are trying to write a script to work on time formats other than the OP has show, your script will fail when the time format contains a space since `last friday`, for example, will be converted to a file name that ends with `last` and a timestamp of `friday` by `"${line##* }"`.

Comment: @EdMorton, have I said that I'm trying to support other formats? Where? As long as you don't provide evidence, I can answer in the same manner: the speed of this script is good enough. When the speed matters, shell is not the right tool by definition. Fast programs are written in C and similar languages.

Comment: Read your answer. You've even highlighted the part about supporting different formats. `Actually, date's -d option argument can be in almost any common format. It can contain month names, time zones, ‘am’ and ‘pm’, ‘yesterday’, etc.`. You specifically mention am and pm - try running your script with a timestamp of `10 am`. Awk programs are usually at least as fast as C programs for manipulating text, often faster, since awk is highly optimized for text processing while C is not and the C code people write by hand to perform the task is usually not the most efficient. Horses for courses.