# gsub function in awk for coloring characters in unix?

Tags: html, shell, unix, awk, gsub

I have a script which produces output.txt file.In that script there are 4   columns are there and they are as below.

```
Filename Date Space status
xyz.txt Nov18 3.8M  On_time
mnp.txt Nov11 8.7M  Delayed
pqr.csv Nov16 9.0M  No_records
```

I am sending the output file through automatic mail, I want to add coloring  the status field like (If status is Delayed,then RED color,On_time,then GREEN and No_records,then Yellow color respectively).

First I am converting output.txt file into output.html which is perfect and I am able to change the background and text color but I am unable to change color for Delay,On_time and n0_records. pls find below code.

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "</head>"
print "<body bgcolor=\"#00ffff\" text=\"#0000FF\">"
print "<pre>"
}
{
gsub(/Fund name/,"<b>Fund name</b>")
gsub(/1234/,"<b>1234</b>")
print $0
}
END{ print "</pre>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
}
' ${PATH1}/output.txt > ${PATH1}/output.html
#  Send mail (uses SENDMAIL)
(
echo "From: Me <me@somewhere>"
echo "To: You <MPAYAL@StateStreet.com>"
echo "Cc: Someone Else <someoneo@somewhere>"
echo "Subject: Message Title"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
echo
echo "<pre>Any text here</pre>"
echo
cat ${PATH1}/output.html
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail "$EMAILTO"
```

Could you please help me on this, I guess I am leaving something gsub field.

Comment: Can values in the Filename or status columns contain a space? If so how can we tell where the status column begins on a given line?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  print "<html>" \
    "<body bgcolor=\"#333\" text=\"#f3f3f3\">" \
    "<pre>"
}

NR == 1 { print $0 }

NR > 1 {
  if      ($NF == "Delayed")     color="red"
  else if ($NF == "On_time")     color="green"
  else if ($NF == "No_records")  color="yellow"
  else                           color="#f0f0f0"

  $NF="<span style=\"color:" color "\">" $NF "</span>"

  print $0
}

END {
  print "</pre>" \
    "</body>" \
    "</html>"
}
' output.txt > output.html
```

*Output*

```html
<html><body bgcolor="#333" text="#f3f3f3"><pre>
Filename Date Space status
xyz.txt Nov18 3.8M <span style="color:green">On_time</span>
mnp.txt Nov11 8.7M <span style="color:red">Delayed</span>
pqr.csv Nov16 9.0M <span style="color:yellow">No_records</span>
</pre></body></html>
```

Thus, you don't need `gsub` as long as you operate on the field values. AWK provides `$n` variables for the n<sup>th</sup> fields, where `n` is a positive integer. Simply compare the field values by referring to the `$n` variables.

In the code above I have used `$NF` for the 4<sup>th</sup> column (number of fields `$NF` is equal to 4, particularly). The first row (`NR == 1`) is printed as is. For the rest of the rows (`NR > 1`), the code modifies the 4<sup>th</sup> column according to its value.

Comment: As you reminded me in [a previous question by the same OP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40640969/1745001) when you said `klm.txt, and mnp.csv look like filenames to me. And a space is allowed to be a part of filename. I wouldn't use a software based on such assumptions.`, that will fail when the first column (Filename) contains spaces. We have to assume the status column could contain spaces too I suppose.

Comment: @EdMorton, heh, indeed. That's why I don't like AWK. Fortunately, the field is the last one, again =) (Or, at least, the filename is the first)

Comment: What tool would fare any better with input that can have unquoted field-separators within the fields? IMHO we can't assume the status field doesn't contain spaces any more than we can assume the file name field doesn't contain spaces so the value the OP wants colored might not be the last space-separated field. I've asked the OP to clarify though so we'll see what he says. There's various approaches would work based on whatever the input format really is.

Comment: @EdMorton, I'd suggest him to use a strict format such as XML, or JSON. The rest depends on his preferences. Personally, I would rather use Perl, or PHP.

Comment: I agree, some kind of strict format would make a lot more sense and solves that problem, no matter what tool you're using to parse it.

Comment: @Ruslan, I am really getting perfect output after running your code, but the bgcolor and unmatched word color is seems grey, so I am unable to read them, Could you please suggest me to change to bgcolor as (cyan/magenta/white) and text color as (black/blue) and hoe to do bold for yellow/green (matched values) please ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Janaranjan, ah, indeed. The default color should be light, e.g. `#f0f0f0`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: A hash lookup of the color would be more efficient than a series of if-else's (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40722767/1745001) so consider doing that in case the input file is large. IMHO it also makes it easier to add/change the mappings in future but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: @edmorton@Ruslan, Thanks for your help :) Is it possible to BOLD or Italic the RED color output i.e Delayed ?

Comment: @Janaranjan, just add conditions in the same manner. [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSFE4ZVVoTnJxSFk).

Comment: @Janaranjan of course, just add the HTML for making text bold at the same place where you're adding the color.

Comment: @Ruslan, a small que, should I align it in proper format (tab separated) like below.
Nov 21   TRIPS11_20161121.txt             09:07   0.001  16       On_Time
Nov 21   AR02_20161121.txt                  09:36   0.000  8        On_Time
Nov 21   AR01_20161121.txt                  09:36   0.027  283      On_Time

But I am getting below

Comment: Nov 21 CHCK01_20161121.txt 09:04 0.000 7 On_Time
Nov 21 CHCK02_20161121.txt 09:20 0.027 218 On_Time
Nov 21 CHCK03_20161121.txt 09:35 0.561 4462 On_Time

Comment: @Janaranjan, you should separate the fields with a symbol that will not appear in the field values. For instance, you might want to use tab character: `awk -F$'\t' '.....' file`. But this still isn't a strict format, since the filenames may contain tab characters. If you you mean you want to align the output, then adjust the sample code accordingly; and, this actually goes beyond the original question.

Comment: @Rulsan, Thanks for the input, Can I take static character by using awk . lets say I have a file name called xyz.txt(7 chars), I want to take 20 static chars output like xyz.txt(13blankspaces) ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Janaranjan, you can use `sprintf`:  `awk '{ printf("%20s", $0) }' <<< 'abc.txt'`. But this already goes beyond the original question, and beyond the format of SO. If you have different questions, please post them as separate questions. If you think the answer solves the question, please accept it.

Comment: @Rulsan, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSFE4ZVVoTnJxSFk, here I got to know for color and bold, if I want to modify the text size, how can I do that ? Thanks a lot ! (I m not that good in html :( )

Comment: @Janaranjan, you haven't asked about text size in _this_ question. If you have questions concerning HTML and CSS, please post another question with `html` and `css` tags. Do you need something else in order to accept _this_ answer? P.S.: `font-size: 15px;`

Answer (score 2):

Not the complete rewrite but just the part you're missing

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{color["On_time"]="green"; 
             color["Delayed"]="red"; 
             color["No_records"]="yellow"} 
 $4 in color{$4="<.. color=\""color[$4]"\">" $4 "</..>"}1' file

Filename Date Space status
xyz.txt Nov18 3.8M <.. color="green">On_time</..>
mnp.txt Nov11 8.7M <.. color="red">Delayed</..>
pqr.csv Nov16 9.0M <.. color="yellow">No_records</..>
```

Comment: Hi karakfa, I don't have only 3 records,the list contains more than 50 and the list is always changing, Could you help me on this please ?

Comment: Number of lines don't matter. Did you try to embed it into your script. You need the list of keywords and color mapping. You may get away with pattern matching but the status should be an enumeration.

Comment: After using your codes I am getting below output. As I told I want to send the output via automatic mail and I am not getting color in my output,Could you please have a look on this please ?
Nov 17 CHCK09_20161117.txt 19:57 0.119 950 <.. color="red">DELAYED***</..>
Nov 18 CHCK01_20161118.txt 08:34 0.442 3517 <.. color="green">On_Time</..>
Nov 18 CHCK02_20161118.txt 08:44 0.001 10 <.. color="green">On_Time</..>
Nov 18 CHCK03_20161118.txt 10:24 0 0 <.. color="yellow">No_Records</..>
Nov 17 ifs01_20161117.txt 19:57 0.000 2 <.. color="red">DELAYED***</..>

Comment: You have to fill .. with html tags.

Comment: Sorry karakfa, I am week in HTML and I don't know how to fill with html tags, Could you help me on this please ? 
Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer so do not accept it, it's just a suggested improvement to @RuslanOsmanov's answer that builds on @karakfa's suggestion of using a hash lookup instead of a series of if-elses to figure out the color to use (compared to @karakfa's suggestion, this shows how to include a default value in the mapping array):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("red green yellow",colors); colors[""] = "#f0f0f0"
    split("Delayed On_time No_records",t); for (i in t) cidx[t[i]]=i
}
{
    $NF = sprintf("<span style=\"color:%s\">%s</span>", colors[cidx[$NF]], $NF)
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Filename Date Space <span style="color:#f0f0f0">status</span>
xyz.txt Nov18 3.8M <span style="color:green">On_time</span>
mnp.txt Nov11 8.7M <span style="color:red">Delayed</span>
pqr.csv Nov16 9.0M <span style="color:yellow">No_records</span>
```

That will improve the script efficiency if the input file is large.